# How to find where an object is created?

Tags: r

I am currently working on improving a code which have different calls to other scripts and I would like to know where an object is created. 
For some of them just using the search option of the text editor works. By just seeing if `obj <-` or `obj =` has any result. But this does not apply by the ones created with the `assign` function. And the ones created in the loaded scripts neither.

The `debug()` function when a error happened tells where it happened even if it is in another script. But there is any  function that tells the line of the code it is created an object? Is there any other tool?

Maybe with `grepl` it could be done but I don't know enough to create such a function...

Comment: would `print`ing `sys.calls()` give you enough info?

Comment: first step in improving your code should be to avoid sourcing other scripts. Even better, make a R package. Do not use global variables. To answer your question, as you suggested, grep for all assignments (<-, =, assign)

Comment: @KarlForner I would like to do so, but it this is not upon me, and while I try to convince people I still need to work with it.

Comment: @SamMason I haven't tested but it might be helpful, from what I read from the help page, but I think it doesn't answer completely my question.

Comment: just stash the value from `sys.calls()` into your object and then inspect/`print` the "right" one when you want.  more context would be needed to help much further, I don't understand why you're referring to assignments at all

Comment: I have lines like this `assign(x=paste("table_", obj.name, sep=""), value=relev_genes)` inside loops, but anyway I don't get how to work with `sys.calls()` could you please explain how to do it in an answer please? Many thanks

Comment: I suspect it might be easier to write the code from scratch than trying to improve code using `assign` in loops.

Comment: I hope I will not need to rewrite the code but I wrote myself these `assign` inside the loops. This is out the question but why I should avoid `assign` functions in loops? In the help page there is an example doing so.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you basically want a function to identify when new objects are created using the debugger. The simplest thing you can do is just type `ls(envir=.GlobalEnv)` in the browser to see what objects you have. Alternatively you could write a function just show you the new objects since the last time you looked (i.e., what new objects have been created (e.g., in the global environment). Here's a function that does that:

```
comparels <- function(){
    oldls <- try(get('oldls', envir=.GlobalEnv))
    if(inherits(oldls, 'try-error'))
        oldls <- list()
    newls <- ls(.GlobalEnv)
    assign('oldls',newls, envir=.GlobalEnv)
    gone <- oldls[!oldls %in% newls]
    added <- newls[!newls %in% oldls]
    list(gone=gone, added=added)
}
```

Here's an example of what it shows you:

```
> comparels()
$gone
list()

$added
[1] "comparels"

> a <- 1
> b <- 2
> c <- 3
> comparels()
$gone
character(0)

$added
[1] "a"     "b"     "c"     "oldls"
```

Then, if you run this on the debugger for your function (here's a simple example below), you'll be able to call `comparels()` and see what new objects have been created at any given point in the function:

```
funtodebug <- function(){
  for(i in 1:100){
    assign(paste('obj',i,sep='_'), i, .GlobalEnv)
  }
}
debug(funtodebug)

> funtodebug()
debugging in: funtodebug()
debug at #1: {
    for (i in 1:100) {
        assign(paste("obj", i, sep = "_"), i, .GlobalEnv)
    }
}
Browse[2]> 
debug at #2: for (i in 1:100) {
    assign(paste("obj", i, sep = "_"), i, .GlobalEnv)
}
Browse[2]> 
debug at #2: i
Browse[2]> 
debug at #3: assign(paste("obj", i, sep = "_"), i, .GlobalEnv)
Browse[2]> 
debug at #2: i
Browse[2]> 
debug at #3: assign(paste("obj", i, sep = "_"), i, .GlobalEnv)
Browse[2]> comparels()
$gone
character(0)

$added
[1] "funtodebug" "obj_1"
```

**EDIT:**
An alternative approach would use Task Callbacks to call the `comparels` function everytime anything happens at the top-level, thus printing anytime new objects are created. Here's a trivial example:

```
addTaskCallback(function(expr,value,ok,visible) {
    print(comparels())
    TRUE},
    name='ls')

a <- 1
b <- 2
a
b
3+3

# remove the callback
removeTaskCallback('ls')
```

This saves you from having to debug your entire program. You can simply trigger the callback before you run your code, then see what happens, and remove the callback.

Comment: This might work but it implies that I know where they might be created (so if I don't know where I should debug every part of my code), instead of "_searching_" where it is created the object obj_1.

Comment: Funny, now each time I introduce a command it prints what have been created or deleted. So I could check where it has been generated each object. Maybe it is asking to much but if I modify an object I don't get any advice, as it has not change from the list oldls, there is a way to know when it changed?   Thanks! I didn't know anything about the TaskCallback.

Comment: I will way if there is a better solution or new ideas before assigning the bounty. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Llopis Yes, you could specify anything in the taskcallback function. For example, the callback could cache all of the current objects, then compare each of them to the cache and point out which have been changed. It's quite flexible.